# Programmatically create new user settings

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, settings

I've created an application that reads an XML configuration file to create the UI.
Within the application I also dynamically add GridSplitters to separate controls and would like the Width of the Grid columns to be saved to the user settings.

This means that the properties within the user settings should also be dynamic.

At creation of the controls I want to be able to do something like this:

```
ColumnDefinition colDef = new ColumnDefinition();
CreateUserSettingIfNotExists("UniqueControlName_Width");
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = Properties.Settings.Default;
binding.Path = "UniqueControlName_Width";
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
colDef.SetBinding(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, binding);
```

How can I programmatically create new user settings to "remember" the Width of the dynamically created Grid?

Comment: how about creating a database in which loads the data on load? that way you could save user settings ?

Comment: Hey MrCoder.. Not a bad idea, but this is a relatively small tool that's part of a way much larger application, so creating a database only for this purpose would be excessive

Comment: The reason I would disagree with you there is because a database is ***made*** to hold data - and you should ***always*** look to try and make your product scalable.

Comment: If you're just trying to save data... is there anything wrong with a simple text file?

Comment: There's not much wrong with using an additional storage besides the user settings for this, but I think it would be nicer to use the user settings. But looking at the (amount of) answers I got, it left me no other options. I used SQLite to store these settings